# MongoDB X509 cert connection

Tags: mongodb, ssl-certificate

I have a X509 user for our Mongo cluster.

> C=AU,ST=Sydney,O=Test Inc.,OU=management:testUst,CN=testapp.test.com

I have created a keystore for this and getting the below error while trying to connect using my Java application.

```
No verified subject name available from client
```

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with
>   error 18: 'No verified subject name available from client' on server
>   test-host.test.com:20904. The full response is {
>   "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1543467173, "i" : 1 } },
>   "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "No verified subject name available from
>   client", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed",
>   "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" :
>   1543467173, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" :
>   "xErnHhtbFM07moBo8x9cV0m4nSY=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : {
>   "$numberLong" : "6628636371827294209" } } } }

Not sure what is missing here ...

Comment: u can check my solution it may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53933372/5577088

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to check on the client connection for a cert auth:

1. Your connection needs to provide the client cert.
2. Your connection needs to provide the CA cert.

2 ways to accomplish providing the CA cert:

1. Add it to the keystore where the client runs
2. Provide it to the connection (cmdline, python, java, javascript, C#, etc.)

Other notes:

- CA Cert needs to be the same for client and server.
- Username needs to match what's in $external.
- Username needs to be the subject of the client cert.

I'm sure there are other things, but these are important things that are easy to miss! Good Luck!